# Nginx, как сделать доп vhost nginx&apache?

Tags: nginx, apache2.2

Вопрос по Nginx нужно сделать доп vhost nginx&apache, vhost не работают, сайт всегда открывается один и тотже в чем ошибка?

Система старая на windows xp server
конфиг Nginx

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error2020_03.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       10.2.0.9:80;
            

        return 301 https://site.ru$request_uri;
#       rewrite ^(.*) https://$host$1 permanent;        
        location ~ \.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|ico|css|js|txt|wsdl)(\?\w+)?$ {
            root C:/vhost/reg.surgut-kpc.ru/web;
            index index.php;
        }

   
        

#       server_name site.ru;
#       access_log logs/nginx_vhost_access.log;
#       error_log logs/nginx_vhost_error.log;

        
        
        
#        location / {
#            proxy_connect_timeout 600;
#            proxy_read_timeout 600;
#            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:80;
#            proxy_set_header Host $host;
#        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
}
 #HTTPS server
    
#   server {
#        listen      10.2.0.9:443;
        
#       ssl on; 
#       ssl_certificate      C:/ssl/certificate.crt;
#       ssl_certificate_key  C:/ssl/secretKey.key;

#       server_name site.ru;
#       access_log logs/nginx_vhost_access.log;
#       error_log logs/nginx_vhost_error.log;
#       location ~ \.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|ico|css|js|txt|wsdl)(\?\w+)?$ {
 #           root c:/vhost/reg.surgut-kpc.ru/web;
  #         index index.php;
#        }  
#    }

#HTTPS

server {
    listen 10.2.0.9:443 ssl;
    
    #ssl_certificate      C:/ssl/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate      C:/ssl/unit_certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  C:/ssl/secretKey.key;
    #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    
#   ssl_session_timeout 20m;
    access_log logs/nginx_vhost_access_2020_11.log;
    error_log logs/nginx_vhost_error_2020_11.log;
    
    location / {
            proxy_connect_timeout 600;
            proxy_read_timeout 600;
            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:80;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
     }


}


#01.12.2020
    server { 
        listen       10.2.0.9:88;
        root C:/vhost/kpc/web/terminal_25;
        index index.php index.html index.htm; 
#       server_name example.com; 
        server_name kpc; 
#       location / { 
#           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php; 
#       } 
        location ~ \.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|ico|css|js|txt|wsdl)(\?\w+)?$ {
            root C:/vhost/kpc/web/terminal_25;
            index index.php;
        }
    }



}
```

Настройка apache

```
 #
# This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2> for detailed information.
# In particular, see 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directives.html>
# for a discussion of each configuration directive.
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
#
# Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
# of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
# server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
# with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so "logs/foo.log"
# with ServerRoot set to "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2" will be interpreted by the
# server as "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/foo.log".
#
# NOTE: Where filenames are specified, you must use forward slashes
# instead of backslashes (e.g., "c:/apache" instead of "c:\apache").
# If a drive letter is omitted, the drive on which httpd.exe is located
# will be used by default.  It is recommended that you always supply
# an explicit drive letter in absolute paths to avoid confusion.

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
# ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to point the LockFile directive
# at a local disk.  If you wish to share the same ServerRoot for multiple
# httpd daemons, you will need to change at least LockFile and PidFile.
#
ServerRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2"

#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 127.0.0.1:80

#Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
#Listen 10.2.0.9:8008
#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
#
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
#
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
#LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
#LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
#LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
#LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
#LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
#LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
#LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
#LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
#LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
#LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
#LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
#LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
#LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
#LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
#LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
#LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
#LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
#LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
#LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
#LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
#LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
#LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
#LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
#LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
#LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
#LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
#LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
#LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
#LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
#LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
#LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
#LoadModule mem_cache_module modules/mod_mem_cache.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
#LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
#LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
#LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
#LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
#LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
#LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
#LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
#LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
#LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
#LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
#LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
#LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
#LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
#LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
#LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
#LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so

<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
<IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>
</IfModule>

# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#

#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
#ServerName reg.surgut-kpc.ru:80

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs"

#
# Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
# to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
# directory (and its subdirectories). 
#
# First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of 
# features.  
#
#<Directory />
#    Options FollowSymLinks
#    AllowOverride None
#    Order deny,allow
#    Deny from all
#</Directory>

<Directory />
       AllowOverride all
       Order deny,allow
</Directory>
#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#
<Directory "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs">
   #
   # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
   # or any combination of:
   #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
   #
   # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
   # doesn't give it to you.
   #
   # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
   # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
   # for more information.
   #
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

   #
   # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
   # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
   #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
   #
   AllowOverride None

   #
   # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
   #
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all

</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
   DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
   Order allow,deny
   Deny from all
   Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

#
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
#ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
#ErrorLog "logs/error_20201116.log"
ErrorLog "logs/error_20201116.log"

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel debug

<IfModule log_config_module>
   #
   # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
   # a CustomLog directive (see below).
   #
   LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
   LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

   <IfModule logio_module>
     # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
     LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
   </IfModule>

   #
   # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
   # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
   # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
   # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
   # logged therein and *not* in this file.
   #
   CustomLog "logs/access_20201116.log" common

   #
   # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
   # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
   #
   #CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
   #
   # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
   # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
   # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
   # Example:
   # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.mynet.com/bar

   #
   # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
   # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
   # Example:
   # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
   #
   # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
   # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
   # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
   # the filesystem path.

   #
   # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
   # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
   # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
   # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
   # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
   # directives as to Alias.
   #
   ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
   #
   # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
   # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
   #
   #Scriptsock logs/cgisock
</IfModule>

#
# "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin">
   AllowOverride None
   Options None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>

#
# DefaultType: the default MIME type the server will use for a document
# if it cannot otherwise determine one, such as from filename extensions.
# If your server contains mostly text or HTML documents, "text/plain" is
# a good value.  If most of your content is binary, such as applications
# or images, you may want to use "application/octet-stream" instead to
# keep browsers from trying to display binary files as though they are
# text.
#
DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule mime_module>
   #
   # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
   # filename extension to MIME-type.
   #
   TypesConfig conf/mime.types

   #
   # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
   # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
   #
   #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
   #
   # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
   # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
   #
   #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
   #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
   #
   # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
   # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
   #
   AddType application/x-compress .Z
   AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

   #
   # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
   # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
   # or added with the Action directive (see below)
   #
   # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
   # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
   #
   #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

   # For type maps (negotiated resources):
   #AddHandler type-map var

   #
   # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
   #
   # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
   # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
   #
   #AddType text/html .shtml
   #AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

LoadModule php5_module c:/php/php5apache2_2.dll  
AddType application/x-httpd-php phtml php 
PHPIniDir "c:/php/"

#
# The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
# contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
# directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
#
#MIMEMagicFile conf/magic

#
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://www.mynet.com/subscription_info.html
#

#
# EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it, 
# memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall is used to deliver
# files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
# be turned off when serving from networked-mounted 
# filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
# broken on your system.
#
#EnableMMAP off
#EnableSendfile off

# Supplemental configuration
#
# The configuration files in the conf/extra/ directory can be 
# included to add extra features or to modify the default configuration of 
# the server, or you may simply copy their contents here and change as 
# necessary.

# Server-pool management (MPM specific)
#Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

# Multi-language error messages
#Include conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf

# Fancy directory listings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

# Language settings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf

# User home directories
#Include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

# Real-time info on requests and configuration
#Include conf/extra/httpd-info.conf

# Virtual hosts
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

# Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
#Include conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf

# Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
#Include conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf

# Various default settings
#Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf

# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
#Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
#
# Note: The following must must be present to support
#       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
#       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
#
<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>


LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
#UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot c:\vhost\%0\web
#VirtualScriptAlias \cgi-bin


#LimitInternalRecursion 50
limitrequestline 65000

Timeout 360
#KeepAliveTimeout 500
#KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 50
#MaxClients 128
ListenBackLog 1024

<Directory "C:/vhost/site.ru">  
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>

#01.12.2020
<Directory "C:/vhost/kpc/web">  
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
#01.12.2020

######## Virtual host ##########

NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
#01.12.2020
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/vhost/kpc/web"
ServerName kpc
ErrorLog "C:/vhost/kpc/web/logs/error.log"
CustomLog "C:/vhost/kpc/web/logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
#01.12.2020
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена не до конца, но при переходе через ip и порт, открывается основной сайт, но если переходить черех адрес хоста и порт, то он переходит туда куда нужно

```
    127.0.0.1:80 ведет на site.ru (образно)
    127.0.0.1:8080 тоже направит на site.ru
    но если ввести site2:8080, тогда мы попадаем именно на нужный виртуальный хост
```